# Request ajax in wordpress response BAD REQUEST

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have some issue with my Wordpress plugin:

```
$.ajax(send_rendered_photo.ajaxurl+"?action=save_photo",{
  type: "POST",
  data:{imgURL: dataURL},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  complete: function(response){

  },
  success: function(data) {
      alert(data.data);
  },
  error: function(data){
      alert("fail");
  }
});
return false;
```

When I have this jQuery code in my js file, response is **null**, and in PHP `$_POST['imgURL']` is **null**, but when I have:

```
$.ajax(send_rendered_photo.ajaxurl,{
  type: "POST",
  data:{
        imgURL: dataURL,
        action: "save_photo",
        },
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  complete: function(response){

  },
  success: function(data) {
      alert(data.data);
  },
  error: function(data){
      alert("fail");
  }
});
return false;
```

in console there is:

> POST http://localhost:81/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad
> Request)

Here is my PHP:

```
function l_m_add_ajax_js(){
  wp_enqueue_script('l_m_ajax_render_photo', plugins_url('scripts/save_photo.js', __FILE__), true);
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
    $protocol = 'https://';
  }
  else{
    $protocol = 'http://';
  }
  $params = array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php',$protocol));
  wp_localize_script('l_m_ajax_render_photo','send_rendered_photo', $params);
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'l_m_add_ajax_js');
add_action('wp_ajax_save_photo', 'save_photo');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_photo', 'save_photo');
function save_photo(){
  $imgURL = $_POST['imgURL'];
  $response = array(
    'success'=>true,
    'data'=>$imgURL
  );
  print json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

I don't know where is the problem. Thanks for any help

EDIT:
There is photos of header and response send_rendered_photo.ajaxurl [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbWjO.png)

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dyFx.png)

This is full js code

```
$("#save").on('click',function(){
                html2canvas(document.getElementById("create")).then(function (canvas) {
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.9);
                alert(dataURL);//dataURL is ok
               $.ajax(send_rendered_photo.ajaxurl+"?action=save_photo",{
                        type: "POST",
                        data: dataURL,
                        dataType: "json",
                        complete: function(response){

                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data); // data is undefined
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                            alert("fail");
                        }
                    });
               return false;
           });
            });
```

EDIT EDIT:
I change in js file "data:{imgURL: dataURL}" to "data:dataURL" and $.ajax to $.post and it worked

Comment: Where is set 'dataURL' variable? Check example of this page https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your **send_rendered_photo.ajaxurl** variable contains correct URL and is not empty?

Comment: I'm sure because in console network is correct URL and send imgURL but request is null

Comment: I just noticed you're capturing the data incorrectly in your **save_photo()** function so your `$_POST['imgURL']` will always be null. What you need to do is capture data like this: `$data = $_POST['data'];` and then you can retrieve imgURL with `$data['imgUrl']` 
Not sure if that will solve your issue.

Comment: It's not help now my PHP is function save_photo(){
 $data = $_POST['data'];
 $imgURL = $data['imgURL'];
 $response = array(
  'success'=>true,
  'data'=>$imgURL
 );
 print json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
Im headers network console is imgURL variable but in response data is null